# Deploying Rails app on Heroku - Images disappears after some time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, carrierwave, rails-activestorage

I deployed a simple **React+Rails** Blog application on Heroku. I deployed separate projects for frontend and backend.

Everything in the application is working fine but the issue is that images disappeared after some time due to routing error. The same URL works for some time but then it stops working.

First I was uploading images using `active_storage` and faced this issue and now I am using `carrierwave` but the issue is still there. I tried different solutions but nothing worked.

I am facing issue only on production and not on localhost.

**Heroku Logs**

[image]

**Production.rb**

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that the files are uploading to your service where you are hosting images?  Are you uploading to S3?

Comment: I'm not using S3. Now I'll try it with S3.

Comment: Heroku does not store images so if you are not hosting them somewhere then that is the issue.  You need to upload the images to S3 or something like that to host the image files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2020/10/11, [Heroku documentation on ActiveStorage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku) says

> Heroku has an “ephemeral” hard drive, this means that you can write files to disk, but those files will not persist after the application is restarted

Recommendation by the same document is

> Instead of storing uploaded files to disk, the best practice is to leverage a cloud file storage service such as Amazon’s S3.

AFAIR, Heorku CLI warns you of this fact. You should have noticed that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the issue by using S3 with active_storage.